# Ordering by multiple values in Symfony

Tags: php, sql

I'm building an symfony application where I have a function that returns all values from my users table ordered by "aanwezig".

"aanwezig" either returns 0, 1 or NULL.

for example:
Right now it returns all values ordered as:

```
1 A
1 C
1 B
0 B
0 A
NULL D
NUlL A
```

I was wondering if it's possible to order them first by value "aanwezig" and then by It's Name in DQL. returning for example:

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
0 A
0 B
NULL A
NUlL D
```

this is what my repository function looks like right now:

```
namespace DigitalArtLabBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByAanwezig()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT u FROM DigitalArtLabBundle:User u ORDER BY u.aanwezig DESC'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

thanks, Julian

Comment: I'm a little uncomfortable with that duplicate @SergioIvanuzzo, that question is premised with the use of `QueryBuilder` - which this question doesn't mention. This uses raw DQL. ( I **do** think it's related though)

Comment: I tried adding ->orderBy() to my script but this just returns error "Attempted to call an undefined method named "orderBy" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Query"."

Comment: `SELECT u FROM DigitalArtLabBundle:User u ORDER BY u.aanwezig DESC, u.name ASC`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Then how it relate to symfony and doctrine2 ?

Comment: thanks! @TurdalievNursultan This solved it

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo I'm doing my project in symfony, DQL is doctrine Query Language right? Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Moopsish please, notice, you don't need to include all tags that your project relate to. You have to use only tags that relate to your question. Current question about sql request, not about Symfony and Doctrine.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo thanks, In the future I will try to avoid unnecessary tags. But I still don't get why the doctrine tag was wrong as I don't think you can do this query in standard sql. Should I have added a DQL tag (if it exists)?